# Jekyll: set permalink based on parameter in potst's front matter

Tags: yaml, rubygems, jekyll, liquid, permalinks

I have simple jekyll site. Every post in `_posts` has paramter `author` in it's front matter:

```yaml
---
layout: post
title: my title
author: John Doe
---

...
```

How should I set permalink in `_confing.yml` if i want it to be `/author/title/`?

For example post above would have permalink:

```
mysite.com/john-doe/my-title/
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using [jekyll_custom_permalink](https://github.com/NiklasEi/jekyll_custom_permalink) plugin.

### Installation

Add the plugin to your site's Gemfile:

```rb
group :jekyll_plugins do
  # your other jekyll plugins...
  gem 'jekyll_custom_permalink', '~> 0.0'
end
```

Then run

```sh
$ bundle install
```

### Usage

Lets assume that you have some options for your collection "projects" defined in `_config`:

```yaml
collections:
  projects:
    output: true
    permalink: projects/:title/
```

You would like to use custom Front Matter in the paths of your projects. For example, it would be great to be able to include the Front Matter variable `type` in the links to your projects, which is defined in every file belonging to the "projects" collection.

```yaml
---
layout: page
type: python
title: MyAwesomeProject
---
Some content
```

You can use the `type` variable in your permalink by first adding it to an array of custom permalink placeholders for the collection, and then adding the placeholder to the permalink setting prefixed with a `:` like every other Jekyll placeholder.

```yaml
collections:
  projects:
    output: true
    custom_permalink_placeholders: ["type"]
    permalink: projects/:type/:title/
```

These settings lead to the "project" page, shown above, to be live at `/projects/python/MyAwesomeProject`.

**SOURCE:** https://github.com/NiklasEi/jekyll_custom_permalink/blob/master/README.md